# Universal App about view controllers

Tags: ios, ios-universal-app

i just want to ask about the universal app that i have created a universal app with two different storyboard one for iphone and other for ipad  , lets assume i created a viewcontroller in both storyboards called mainview so should i create different classes for the storyboard of iphone and ipad or should i create one class and assign to both mainview iphone and mainview ipad .

ignore the code below

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ApplicationUtility getPlistData:KEY_REGISTER_DATA]] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[ApplicationUtility getPlistData:KEY_REGISTER_DATA]];

NSLog(@"%@",str);

if([str isEqualToString:@"Signed up successful"])
{

    username.text = @"";
    firstname.text = @"";
    lastname.text = @"";
    email.text = @"";
    supass.text = @"";
    suconfirmpass.text = @"";
    country.text = @"";
    postal.text = @"";
    dob.text = @"";
    titl.text = @"";
    [priv1 setSelected:NO];
    [priv2 setSelected:NO];

    [male setSelected:NO];
    [female setSelected:NO];

}
```

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere?  And what does *ignore the code below* mean?

Comment: Why do we ignore the code? It's beautiful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should create one class for both storyboards if you can, so if you have any special treatment for any, you can put some `if` statements in your code.

You can take a look at Apple's doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24).

Comment: But the app i am creating is very complex and it'll be really difficult for me to handle it that way ... i have created different class for each ..... is it ok

Comment: Yes it is OK, but managing two copies of the same class sharing the logic and the business will be ugly latter, especially when you are going to update the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
in storyboard u should call a ipad storybard on ipad condition and u shoud call iphone storyboard on iphone condition and condition is below...
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
              //for iphone storyboard
}
else
{
              //for ipad storyboard
}
```